# PHP resize image before save to mysql database?

Tags: php, database, image-manipulation

After I got the post, how to resize to a smaller width (maximum width is 80, min also 80) and what should I check for security purposes?

My current code:

```
if(!empty($_FILES)) {
# Resize Image function
$return=true;
function resizeImage($originalImage,$toWidth,$toHeight){
    // Get the original geometry and calculate scales
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($originalImage);
    $xscale=$width/$toWidth;
    $yscale=$height/$toHeight;

    // Recalculate new size with default ratio
    if ($yscale>$xscale){
        $new_width = round($width * (1/$yscale));
        $new_height = round($height * (1/$yscale));
    }
    else {
        $new_width = round($width * (1/$xscale));
        $new_height = round($height * (1/$xscale));
    }

    // Resize the original image
    $imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    $imageTmp     = imagecreatefromjpeg ($originalImage);
    imagecopyresampled($imageResized, $imageTmp, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

    return $imageResized;
}

// Get the file information
$userfile_name = $_FILES['profile_picture']['name'];
$userfile_tmp  = $_FILES['profile_picture']['tmp_name'];
$userfile_size = $_FILES['profile_picture']['size'];
$userfile_type = $_FILES['profile_picture']['type'];
$filename = basename($_FILES['profile_picture']['name']);
$file_ext = strtolower(substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1));

//Only process if the file is a JPG and below the allowed limit
if((!empty($_FILES["profile_picture"])) && ($_FILES['profile_picture']['error'] == 0)) {
    $allowed_image_types = array('image/pjpeg'=>"jpg",'image/jpeg'=>"jpg",'image/jpg'=>"jpg",'image/png'=>"png",'image/x-png'=>"png",'image/gif'=>"gif");
    $allowed_image_ext = array_unique($allowed_image_types); // Do not change this
    foreach ($allowed_image_types as $mime_type => $ext) {
        if($file_ext==$ext ){
            $return=false;
            break;
        } else {
            $return=true;
        }
    }

    if ($userfile_size > (7*1048576)) { # 7 means 7 mb
        $return=false;
    }
} else {
    $return=false;
}

//Everything is ok, so we can upload the image.
if (strlen($return)==0){
    $widthAndHeight = getimagesize($userfile_tmp . "." . $file_ext); //EDITED QUESTION
    $width  = $widthAndHeight[0];
    $height = $widthAndHeight[1];

    if ($width > 80){
        $scale = 80/$width;
        $height = $height * $scale;
        $data = resizeImage($userfile_name,80,$height,$scale);
        $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
    } else {
        $data = mysql_real_escape_string($userfile_name);
    }

    $update = mysql_query("UPDATE `avatar` set image = '{$data}' WHERE userid = '" .  $_SESSION['userid'] . " . '");
} else {
    $return=false;
}
```

The datatype in mysql database is MediumBlob since it only store small file

Sorry for not mention my problem, the code its not working. The error is:

```
Warning: getimagesize(C:\wamp\tmp\php991B.tmp.png) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\XXX\avatar.php on line 82**strong text**
```

Comment: your problem has nothing to do with database. it says "file not found". check file path.

Comment: Having files stored in the database, you have to start separate PHP process to serve each image on the page and make another connect to the database. It's inacceptable overhead for the web-development. All static data like images should be served as is, not through dynamic page.

Answer (score 4):

Better way will be - to store the image in file system and store a ref to the file in the database. (For the resizing you can use GD library)

Try this link: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php

Comment: I did research on storing image on file system and database, each has its own pros and cons. Although majority prefer file system.

Comment: but a 80x80 RGB image is only 18.75KB

Comment: Agree with Don, thats why I store it in Blob

Comment: I prefer ImageMagick resize because with GD is harder to handle Lanczos resampling.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't really need to write your own code for this, you can try out some of the solutions that are already out there.

This is an excellent script 
http://phpthumb.gxdlabs.com/

I am not sure if you can save image data to a database using it, but worst case scenario is

you resize the image and save it to a local folder
use file_get_contents to read the image and save to db
delete temp image on server.

But I agree with those who say you should store the images in the filesystem, not the database.