# Resize image before saving to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, image-resizing, image-upload

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312204/php-resize-image-before-save-to-mysql-database) but I'm stuck on the final bit!

The following code takes a file sent by an HTML form and checks its dimensions against two predefined values, `$maxwidth` and `$maxheight`. If it's too wide, it resizes the image.

All I want it to do next is to reassign the newly resized image to the original variable `$tmpName` so that the rest of the script can process it.

The following code returns these errors:

```
Warning: fopen() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in /var/www/vhosts/galleryimaginem.com/httpdocs/img/upload.php on line 43

Warning: filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for Resource id #4 in /var/www/vhosts/galleryimaginem.com/httpdocs/img/upload.php on line 44

Warning: fread(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /var/www/vhosts/galleryimaginem.com/httpdocs/img/upload.php on line 44

Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /var/www/vhosts/galleryimaginem.com/httpdocs/img/upload.php on line 46
```

I reckon I'm pretty close to getting it but can anyone help? Thanks.

```
if (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0) { 

      // Temporary file name stored on the server
      $tmpName  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];  

            list($width,$height)=getimagesize($tmpName);

            if ($width>$height && $width>$maxwidth) {
                $newheight=($height/$width)*$maxwidth;
                $newwidth=$maxwidth;
                $imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
                $imageTmp     = imagecreatefromjpeg ($tmpName);
                imagecopyresampled($imageResized, $imageTmp, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
                $tmpName=$imageResized;

                // My problem lies somewhere here ^^^^
            }

      // Read the file 
      $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
      $data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
      $data = addslashes($data);
      fclose($fp);


      // Create the query and insert
      // into our database.
      $query = "INSERT INTO tblPrints ";
      $query .= "(title,full_image) VALUES ('IMG-TEST','$data')";
      $results = mysql_query($query, $link);

      // Print results
      print "Thank you, your file has been uploaded.";

}
else {
   print "No image selected/uploaded";
}
```

Comment: instead of assigning it to the $imgTmp variable assign it to $tmpName simple

Comment: What do you mean exactly, Yasir?

Comment: in processing u assign to a new variable $imageTmp just continue with the $tmpName so the name of your variable will not change and u can process it with the same name.

Comment: Try to escape (with mysql_real_escape()) the $tmpName AFTER you open file with fopen.

Comment: $tmpName contains the name as String but imagecreatetruecolor returns a resource handle for an image object. Two completely different types. Just save the resized image again after resampling into a new file and use the path to it as String in $tmpName.

Answer (score 0):

Lines 6-17 replace the filename with the image data itself - that's the meaning of

```
Warning: fopen() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given
```

So in the lines that follow,

```
  // Read the file 
  $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
  $data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
  $data = addslashes($data);
```

you don't need to read the file. If the conditional process has executed, you just need

```
$data = $tmpname // sounds strange, remember: $tmpname is not the name any more
```

Comment: So, to elaborate a bit more, the script works when lines 6-17 are taken out. That is to say, the original upload (stored in `$_FILES[]`) can be processed and successfully added to the database.

What happens is that on line 14 when the variable is changed by those lines of code the new image is now being referenced in a way that the subsequent coding can't interpret.

Can anyone see what I am missing or have done wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Er... I totally misunderstood your lines 6-17. I will revise the answer completely.